# How to add a gstreamer plugin?

Tags: c++, c, plugins, installation, gstreamer

I have made a simple GStreamer plugin but GStreamer inspect/launch tools aren't picking up my source. I copied the dll over to the gstreamer libs directory, deleted the gstreamer registry folder in c/users/user/.gstreamer-0.10/ ran gst-inspect-0.10 and it recreated the registry file but it still didn't pick up my custom plugin. Am i missing a step here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to put ifndef macros over the PACKAGE constant.